# How do i Calculate Fill Order Rate Using Sales Order Line Item

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

We are trying to write a query to find out how much of the order was fullfilled in the first invoice on that order. Look at ArTrnInvoice table for Invoice info and OrderDetail for orders info. Compare qty ordered on each sales order line to what was fulfilled on the first invoice on that order

We tried

```
select  case when SalesOrderLine>0 THEN QtyInvoiced /MOrderQty *100 Else  End as Order_fILL_RATE    FROM OrderDetail a Left JOIN
                                OrderHeader b ON a.SalesOrder = b.SalesOrder
                            WHERE  b.Order Status ='9'
```

Basically,Trying to Output :

How much of the order was fullfilled in the first invoice - Let' say I ordered 2000$ worth of items. And Business Org invoiced this to me in two parts. First 1800$ within 10 days and then another 200$ later (or didn't ship this at all). In this case fill rate = 90%

**Given Conditions**

We  have sql server 2012. Trying to  calculate Fill Order Rate  Using Order Line Item.

We have 3 table which consist of  OrderHeader Info,OrderDetail Info,  Invoice  info table .

Structure of  these tables  are  Here  in link:

OrderDetail Table

Structure is

OrderHeader Table DDL

Also OrderStatus='9' means Fulfilled Order.

Any help on it would be much appreciated ?

Comment: Please include your table structures in your question. Part of the point of StackOverflow is that people in the future can refer to questions here and use the answers to help with similar issues. That's not possible if relevant parts of the question are in links that will eventually become broken. Also, it usually helps to have sample data that exhibits the issue along with expected output.

Comment: We have  edited  In the Question for Sample Data and DDL  statement.